# Error in Nuxt store setup-vuex] unknown action type: fetchProfiles

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new to NUXT, need help. I am trying to setup store and using it in one component but getting these errors in console.

> ```
> getting messages
> ```

```
   'state' should be a method that returns an object in store/profiles.js.
```

> ```
>       [vuex] unknown action type: fetchProfiles
>       [vuex] unknown getter: allProfiles
> ```

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
 name: "Profiles",
 methods: {
   ...mapActions(["fetchProfiles"])
 },
 computed: mapGetters(["allProfiles"]),
 created() {
   this.fetchProfiles();
 }
};
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Where have you defined your state for that store?

Comment: state is in store folder store/profiles.js
Here is it's code
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  profiles: []
};

const getters = {
  allProfiles: state => state.profiles
};

const actions = {
  async fetchProfiles({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get("http://161.35.7.108/profiles");

    commit("setProfiles", response.data);
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setProfiles: (state, profiles) => (state.profiles = profiles)
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const state = ()=> ({ 
    profiles: [], 
})
```

The state must be a method, you are directly returning an object.

Answer (score 0):

You use the store in module mode.

You need to tell in witch module it is:

```
methods: {
   ...mapActions(["profiles/fetchProfiles"])
},
   computed: mapGetters(["profiles/allProfiles"]),
};
```

You should add `profiles/` infront of it.
Without `profile/` it searches for an `store/index.js` file